# Phalcon not rending view action when using router

Tags: view, routes, action, phalcon

I have a problem with Phalcon PHP. It cannot display the view of an action of a controller when using with routing

Ex: **http://vngarena.com/game/kieu-hung-2472.html**

The result just displayed the text from gamedetail action: "This is gamedetail Action", not the title of the game in the view.

**`app/config/routes.php`:**

```
$router = new Phalcon\Mvc\Router();
$router->add("/game/([a-z0-9\-]+)-([0-9]+).html", array(
    'namespace' => 'Vokuro\Controllers\\',
    'controller' => 'Frontend',
    'action' => 'gamedetail',
    'slug' => 1,
    'id' => 2
))->setName("game-detail");
```

**`/app/controllers/FrontendController.php`**

```
use Vokuro\Models\Terms;
use Vokuro\Models\Games;

class FrontendController extends ControllerBase
{

    public function gamedetailAction($slug, $id) {

        echo "This is gamedetail Action";
        $game = Games::findFirstById($id);

        if (!$game) {
            $this->flash->error("Game does not exist");
        }
        else {
            $this->view->game = $game;
            $this->view->screenshots = $game->screenshot;
       }
    }

}
```

**`app/views/frontend/gamedetail.volt`**

```
{{ game.title }
```

**`app/views/layouts/frontend.volt`**

```
{{ content() }}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Things to check:

- View on the server has the correct read/write permissions
- I think Phalcon is case sensitive for naming. Note how you've used "frontend" and "Frontend".

Comment: That's great! I changed 'Frontend' to 'frontend' in router configuration and it works.

Comment: I want just to point out that phalcon *Controller/Router* is case *insensetive* and Volt/View are case *sensetive* when matching template names (as my version of phalcon 1.3.2).